# Type mismatch unloading userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform, type-mismatch

I'm trying to unload a userform ("DataEntry") when the active cell is not in the appropriate sheet (index number 2). I am getting a "Type Mismatch '13" after the messagebox, and I don't know why, can anyone help?

This sub is in a module, not the userform. I have tried setting up a sub in the userform and calling that (single line sub "Unload Me", but I get the same result.

```
Sub unloadform()

    If ActiveSheet.Index <> 2 Then
        MsgBox "The schedule must be selected to enter data"
        Unload DataEntry
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Update:
I occurred to me to put this code in the userform initialize sub, (I don't want the userform to load if the correct sheet is not selected). Now I get a Runtime Error '91'

Tried replacing Unload Me with Unload DataEntry (the name of the userform), (same result), and replacing it with Unload VBA.Userforms("DataEntry"), which throws a Runtime '13' error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Schedule must be selected to enter data"
    Unload Me
Else:
     'other code if correct sheet is selected
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is calling this code?  Why not put it in the userform itself?  Would also be helpful to show the code which opens the userform.

Comment: It's not unlikely the error is actually inside the UserForm's module. Use `F8` to step through the code and see what line is causing the error.

Comment: The user form has many tabs (multipages, forgive me if I use poor terminology I'm very new to  userforms); I have code for each page in separate modules as putting everything in the userform would crowd it and make subs difficult to find. At the moment, as I am developing the userform, I am running it manually, so there's nothing as yet calling the userform.

Comment: I have stepped through, after the msgbox is displayed, the error is shown - no line is highlighted, so I don't know how to locate the error in that way.

Comment: Any code that is executed by a trigger within the form when you Unload it?

Comment: No, nothing is triggered by unloading it - unless that can happen accidentally (new to userforms). I will post the code in the user form tomorrow, I have had to step away from work now, but il allait it does is call subs from modules according to wihich page is selected.